# Drawing pie charts on google map using for loop does not functioning well

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I tried to draw pi charts on several locations in a google map. I came up with a code which draws pie charts on several locations using a for loop. I need to add a click event to all the pie charts to display a window with pie chart details. But the on click event is not functioning well. Could anyone please help me to come with a solution for this issue.
The following is the code I tried with.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://code.google.com//apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.10&sensor=false&.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load( 'visualization', '1', { packages:['corechart'] });
        ChartMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;
        ChartMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {
            $( this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget ).append( this.$div );
        };

        ChartMarker.prototype.onRemove = function() {
            this.$div.remove();
        };

        ChartMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
            var marker = this;
            var projection = this.getProjection();
            var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel( this.get('position') );

            this.$div.css({
                left: position.x,
                top: position.y,
                display: 'block'
            })

            this.$inner
                    .html( '<img src="' + this.get('image') + '"/>' )
                    .click( function( event ) {
                        var events = marker.get('events');
                        events && events.click( event );
                    });

            this.chart = new google.visualization.PieChart( this.$inner[0] );
            this.chart.draw( this.get('chartData'), this.get('chartOptions') );
        };


        function drawChart(marker, data, event, location) {


            var options = {'title':'Event : '+event+'  Location : '+location,
                'width':400,
                'height':150,
                slices: {0: {color: 'orange'}, 1:{color: 'green'}, 2:{color: 'yellow'}, 3: {color: 'blue'}, 4:{color: 'red'}}};

            var node        = document.createElement('div'),
                    infoWindow  = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
                    chart       = new google.visualization.PieChart(node);
            chart.draw(data, options);
            infoWindow.setContent(node);
            infoWindow.open(marker.getMap(),marker);
        }
        function ChartMarker( options ) {
            this.setValues( options );
            this.$inner = $('<div>').css({
                position: 'relative',
                left: '-50%', top: '-50%',
                width: options.width,
                height: options.height,
                fontSize: '1px',
                lineHeight: '1px',
                padding: '2px',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                cursor: 'default'
            });
            this.$div = $('<div>')
                    .append( this.$inner )
                    .css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        display: 'none'
                    });
        };
        function drawPieCharts(map,latlang){
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                [ 'Task', 'Hours per Day' ],
                [ 'Work', 11 ],
                [ 'Eat', 2 ],
                [ 'Commute', 2 ],
                [ 'Watch TV', 2 ],
                [ 'Sleep', 7 ]
            ]);
            var options = {
                fontSize: 8,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                legend: {position: 'none'}
            };
            var marker = new ChartMarker({
                map: map,
                position: latlang,
                width: '250px',
                height: '100px',
                chartData: data,
                chartOptions: options,
                events: {
                    click: function( event ) {
                        drawChart(marker,data)
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        function initialize() {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856)
            var markers = [
                [ -33.890542, 151.274856, 50,40,21,40],
                [-33.923036, 151.259052, 67,89,23,67],
                [-34.028249, 151.157507, 45,67,23,90],
                [-33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187,456,234,789,90],
                [-33.950198, 151.259302,456,34,90,23]
            ];
            var mapOptions = {
                center: latLng,
                zoom: 12,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                    mapOptions);
            for(var k=0;k<markers.length;k++){
                var location = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[k][0],markers[k][1])
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    [ 'Task', 'Hours per Day' ],
                    [ 'Work', markers[k][2] ],
                    [ 'Eat', markers[k][3] ],
                    [ 'Commute',markers[k][4] ],
                    [ 'Watch TV', markers[k][5] ],
                    [ 'Sleep', markers[k][6] ]
                ]);
                var options = {
                    fontSize: 8,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    legend: {position: 'none'}
                };
                var marker = new ChartMarker({
                    map: map,
                    position: location,
                    width: '250px',
                    height: '100px',
                    chartData: data,
                    chartOptions: options,
                    events: {
                        click: function( event ) {
                            drawChart(marker,data)
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body >
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the major issue is this:

```
var marker = new ChartMarker({
                    map: map,
                    position: location,
                    width: '250px',
                    height: '100px',
                    chartData: data,
                    chartOptions: options,
                    events: {
                        click: function( event ) {
                            drawChart(marker,data)
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Inside the loop you overwrite `marker` and  `data` on each iteration, so the arguments passed to `drawChart` will always be the same arguments (created on the last iteration).

Use a anonymous function with closures to avoid it:

```
(function(location,data){
    var marker = new ChartMarker({
                        map: map,
                        position: location,
                        width: '250px',
                        height: '100px',
                        chartData: data,
                        chartOptions: options,
                        events: {
                            click: function( event ) {
                                drawChart(marker,data)
                            }
                        }
                    });

})(location,data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help given. I have some other issue in this. I tried to draw more than 20 markers on the map.The click event functionality was working fine. But to close the window with pie chart details does not work well. We have to click on close icon multiple times to close the window. If could, please help me to find the issue with this.

Comment: You add new infowindows on each click to the map(when it happens that the infowindow didn't close on first click, observe the shadow of the infowindow, I guess it's brighter, because you've closed a infowindow, but there are multiple windows at the same position). Fixed code(also brings the  last infowindow into front): http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Vg6jm/